# How do I plot asset stock prices in R?

Tags: r, finance

I'm trying to plot asset stock prices in R. I'm downloading the data in csv format from Yahoo Finance and then importing it to R so I can run some statistical tests on it and draw a few plots.

I'm currently trying to plot the closing price vs the date, and I'm not having a lot of success. R is just plotting it as a series of distinct points and won't join these points up with lines, despite me trying to use the argument type = "l".

```
price <- read.csv("~/Downloads/AAPL.csv")
plot(price$Date,price$Close,type="l")
```

I'm just grabbing the data from here: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/history?p=AAPL

I get an output like this every time, regardless of what kind of extra arguments I try.

[image: this]

For example, I tried to make it red, didn't change at all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that *pric$Date* is a factor (categorical variable) and not a number. You can convert the date string to a Posix timestamp with *as.POSIXlt*, and then compute a floating point representation therefrom, e.g. *year + yday/366*.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
price$Date = as.Date(price$Date)
plot(price$Date,price$AAPL.Close,type="l",col=4)
```

or better

```
library(quantmod)

fro = '2014-07-31'
Apple = getSymbols('AAPL',auto.assign = F,from=fro)
chartSeries(Apple,subset = "last 3 years")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a package unless you want to create candlestick charts.

```
df <- read.csv("AAPL.csv")
```

> ```
>  > str(df)                      
>  'data.frame':   254 obs. of  7 variables:
>   $ Date     : Factor w/ 254 levels "2019-07-10","2019-07-11",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
>   $ Open     : num  202 203 202 204 205 ...
>   $ High     : num  204 204 204 206 206 ...
>   $ Low      : num  202 202 202 204 204 ...
>   $ Close    : num  203 202 203 205 204 ...
>   $ Adj.Close: num  201 199 201 203 202 ...
>   $ Volume   : int  17897100 20191800 17595200 16947400 16866800 14107500 18582200 20929300 22277900 18355200 ...
> ```

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date)  # Otherwise it is treated as a factor variable
```

> ```
>  > str(df)                   
>  'data.frame':   254 obs. of  7 variables:
>   $ Date     : Date, format: "2019-07-10" "2019-07-11" "2019-07-12" "2019-07-15" ...
>   $ Open     : num  202 203 202 204 205 ...                                               
>   $ High     : num  204 204 204 206 206 ...
>   $ Low      : num  202 202 202 204 204 ...
>   $ Close    : num  203 202 203 205 204 ...
>   $ Adj.Close: num  201 199 201 203 202 ...
>   $ Volume   : int  17897100 20191800 17595200 16947400 16866800 14107500 18582200 20929300 22277900 18355200 ...
> ```

```
plot(y=df$Close, x=df$Date, col="red", type = "l")  # look at ?plot for more details
```

[image]